# I want a codes which redirect to my website when JavaScript used on wrong site

Tags: javascript, security

I want to secure JavaScript Codes. I secure my JavaScript with https://javascriptobfuscator.com/ but it can also stolen from view source.

I want a codes which redirect to my website when JavaScript used on wrong site.

This is possible I know but I don't know how?

Comment: "Protect" "Javascript"... yeah... From whom? Why?

Comment: It's impossible to protect your javascript code. You can write things in PHP and run so user can't even know your code, but no. Obfuscating your code doesn't do anything. Using a beautifier will make your code difficult to understand, but still understandable.

Comment: You cannot hide javascript code that you need to execute. If you really have something that needs to be hidden, then it must be done server side and the javasript will just fetch the result.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is check the return of `location.host` or `location.hostname`.
To redirect to another URL you would change the value of `location`:

```
location = "https://mywebsite.com";
//or alternatively
location.assign("https://mywebsite.com");
```

*However*, the redirection <del>may</del> will be prevented by [Cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) policies (see Michael's comment). So you could just display an alert dialog.

```
alert("Don't use my script on your website");
```

The person trying to use your code on their website will be warned during development by this alert.

In any case, your obfuscated code can still be changed and someone that is determined will remove these "security" measures and it can even be deobfuscated.
Are you sure all of this is needed ? Modifying a stolen code to make it work on another website can be harder/longer than just rewriting a similar code. Apart if you are doing something very special and new, I think you are just losing time by trying to protect your code.

Comment: `the redirection may be prevented`. If it's another domain, it will *always* be prevented

Comment: @Michael — No, it won't. The Same Origin Policy prevents a JavaScript running on site A from reading data on site B. It doesn't stop it telling the browser to load site B.